# contact form in asp MVC that sends an email with submitted email address as the sender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

Using html and php, I can easily make a working contact form that sends an email having the sender is the email address submitted by the user to the input field. How can I do the same thing in asp MVC? I have searched the internet but all I found was the sender is hardcoded, like we cannot take it from and input field and make it as a sender.

Comment: So, you want people to be able to spoof other peoples email addresses?  You do realize that this is how spam is created, right?

Comment: You're going to have to post some code showing what you ahve tried.

Comment: thank you so much, for all your help. I got it all now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is, you shouldn't allow arbitrary email addresses to be entered by a user, because this can be used to create spam.  But beyond that, many email domains now rely on SPF records (Sender Policy Framework) to control what computers can send email from a specific domain, so many kinds of emails you might enter simply will never get delivered due to spam rejection.

If this is strictly an internal app, with internal email addresses, then you should extract their email address from their authentication.

In any event, it's relatively simple to add a sender.  You just do this:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com");
```

Normally, I wouldn't say something like this.. but since you insisted you searched the internet...

I went to google and typed ".net send email" and the very first link was to this blog entry which explains exactly what you want.  Not sure how you scoured the net looking for it when it was the very first result.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432854

Comment: thank you sir, now I see it clearly. Sorry for late reply, I fell asleep. It is dawn here, I have been coding for the whole night. again thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

```
    public ActionResult SendComent(string sender, string body)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.To.Add("MyEmailAddress");
        msg.Subject = "contact";
        msg.From = msg.Sender = new MailAddress(sender);
        SmtpClient cl = new SmtpClient("MySMPTServer");
        cl.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail","password");
        cl.Send(msg);
        return View("ThankYou")
    }
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: It is the asnwer, unfortunately I fell asleep because it is dawn and I have been coding for the whole night. I can't make two answers for it, sorry. but again, thanks